# Cannot connect UNIX system to Hazelcast cluster

Tags: windows, unix, hazelcast

We are trying to connect multiple machines in same network with Hazelcast. The code:

```
Config config = new Config();
HazelcastInstance h = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
ITopic<String> topic = h.getTopic("my-distributed-topic");
..... some logic ....
```

When connecting one UNIX(Ubuntu) and Windows, they are able to connect. But with Ubuntu and MAC, MAC and MAC or Ubuntu and Ubuntu it does not work. We wonder if there would be some known issue with UNIX machines?

Comment: Any firewall active? And no, no know problems. We have Windows, Mac, Linux machines in development and there are no issues.

Answer (score 1):

@samutamm do you have the known problems with multicast in your network? Could you try tcp/ip config

```
Config config = new Config();
final NetworkConfig networkConfig = config.getNetworkConfig();
networkConfig.setPortAutoIncrement(true);
networkConfig.getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
networkConfig.getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().addMember("127.0.0.1").setEnabled(true);
```

Thank you